# How would you name this font?

Tags: fonts, font-design, bitmap

**Bold text is for edits, which are important.**

**Breaking news: ttf Unicode version released at https://typedesign.netlify.com/customfont.html**

I made a bitmap font resembling my handwriting (I improved it over the years in school, removing the letter linking, using dotted 0, styled i, j, g, m, ...) **(officially my handwriting font *is* Custom Font)**, and for now I'm calling it "Custom Font" **(it is)**.
Here is a picture of this font, in my favorite theme:

[image]

The question is: Pick a name for this font. The "Custom Font" name is a placeholder **(not)**.

If you want this font (with the name "Custom Font"), go to https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezc2x5tqfmf7kyd/fontboth.fon?dl=0. **(recently the character set has been changed and sizes 8 and 12 removed: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9rpnk33qeurk65/customfont.fon?dl=0)**

**Edit: Do not treat this question seriously. Case closed: "Custom Font" is the perfect and official name. I like to think of "custom" as being short for "customized". The name won't be changed.**

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Unfortunately, [idea-gathering questions are not a good fit for this site](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/183/19174). (Also, if you want anybody to help you with that question, you need to provide some information on what you want the name to reflect.)

Comment: Very nice brackets!!! I think a lot of font designers working on monospaced fonts get them wrong. These are good!

Comment: Also I used underline in my style, matching the bottom of letters instead of being under it.

Comment: I'll go with Custom Font. The size 9 is the primary size.

Answer (score 2):

Groch Monospaced

Subjective reasons:

- not used
- it can later be a part of font family Groch
- Groch is short, it's an one shot output from the mouth
- tries to tell that glyphs have no snobby curved outlines and they have equal width
- if this is your first own computer font, It well earns to get something of the name that you use

Additions after seeing comments: Monospaced is widely used. Groch Lettering, Groch Old Screen or Groch CRT also may be fine. Groch CRT Regular is not too long.

Comment: The monospaced font is going to be the regular one by the way. If I make a proportional version, it won't be the regular version. The font is only used in my handwriting and as the default font in my computer. Also it's all yellow text on black background, like in picture - I have a high contrast extension (that has an option inverting the colors and turning them into black/yellow color spectrum) and a dark theme in Chrome, too.

Comment: Thanks for the file. delete the link commet soon if you do not want the wrong name to spread. Put it back after renaming.

Comment: I don't feel like renaming it. I'll remain on "Custom Font" for now.

Comment: Maybe Bowski or Broski or Brookings? Bracts, fonty mcfontface, costume font, funt, noName, front, Jeffers, etc. The possibilities are literally limitless.

Comment: That's the point, the possibilities are limitless.

Comment: Your name was not accepted. See important edits (bold) in the question.

Comment: @PiotrGrochowski That's no problem. You decide, its your font. Custom resembles also a duty collector bureau.

Answer (score 0):

Given the predilection for yellow, and the manner in which Grochowski is pronounced, I'd go with **Grosky**.

Comment: This theme (yellow on black) is from High Contrast #1, and it was nice because it was dark. The yellow text from it seemed nice, and I sticked with it, instead of white or green text. But not all elements used yellow on black, for example window titles had the weird white on dark green. So I modified it to be all yellow on black except for "grayed" texts (which are red), selections (black on green), inactive window titles (green on black) and links (also green)

Comment: Your name was not accepted. See important edits (bold) in the question.

Comment: I think we're on the same page.